# Change ASP.NET Identity to use existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 with a Database-First workflow. I've created the Identity tables (`AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` etc.) in my existing database however I'm having problems getting the **register** and **login** functionality to work properly.

This is the `IdentityModels.cs` class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyConnectionString") // I use "MyConnectionString" instead of "DefaultConnection" 
    {
    }
```

This is what the EF connection string from the `web.config` looks like

```
<connectionStrings><add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=My-Pc\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyExistingDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And for good measure here's the context class generated from the edmx

```
public partial class MyConnectionString : DbContext
{
    public MyConnectionString()
        : base("name=MyConnectionString")
    {
    }
```

To me all seems well and it should be able to create users in the database however I'm getting the following error when logging in or trying to register respectively:

For login:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context
>
> Line 73: var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
>   model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
>   ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

For register:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the
>   current context
>
> Line 155: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,
>   model.Password);
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
>   ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Most articles around seems to be focusing on Code-First and how to go from LocalDb to SQLExpress etc. and how to change the connection string however I haven't been able to solve this problem for a good amount of time.

**Edit, solution**: As @ChrFin mentioned you could use them both side by side which is what I ended up doing. I simply added a new [*regular*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) connection string in `web.config` and let it point to the existing database. PS. remember that the connection string name cannot be the same as the existing one and must be the same you provide to the `ApplicationDbContext` constructor.

Comment: Update you edmx file form database.Simply right click on file in solution explorer update from database

Comment: Is ApplicationUser  in your ApplicationDbContext Context, you should define DBSet<ApplicationUser> there.

Comment: @J.W. I'm not quite with you on that one, why would I have to define that?

Comment: Because the error says The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I THINK this scenario is not supported by ASP.NET Identity as it needs a `DbContext` which extends `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` (or similar).

Why are you forcing Identity into your DB-First context?
You can use a Code-First context for Identity alongside your other DB-First context without problems...

Comment: If you by forcing mean that I can simply supply DefaultConnection to the constructor and have it create a new DB then I have already got that working. However it seems to me as a bad 'patch up'. What I essentially also want is to create relationships with the existing tables I have and i.e. AspNetUsers

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong: As I understand you are trying to use your DB-first context with the login/register functionality instead of the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`-based code-first context - is that not the case?

Comment: Yes you're right, I think I got a little confused as well. Anyways, that is why I supplied the same connection string name to it in its constructor. I can't see how I would go about it if I were to use it alongside, could you possibly explain this a little further.

Comment: There is not much to explain: Use your `ApplicationDbContext` for `ASP.NET Identity` (you can look that up in the default MVC template) and your DB-first context for the rest. As long as the tables fit both models you are good to go...

Comment: That part I'm familiar with but what I don't understand is how would you create a relationship between two tables in separate databases. I'm not sure what you mean by "As long as the tables fit both models.."

Comment: No, you use the same database just two different contexts, but both point to the same DB. P.S.: Of course you need to create the tables in that DB...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61337/discussion-between-twice-and-chrfin).

Comment: Even more than a year later this is the best option to use. One connection string for the DB first side, and a separate connection string that just manages the Identity side.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolved this problem by following these steps:

- 1-create aspnetuser etc tables on your database (whatever DB you want
  to use)
- simply connect the application with that database not using entity framework,   i'm saying just simple connection.
- you will find connection string in web.config file.
- place this connection string into identity model clsss
- your Register and Token methods now running
- now you can use entity framewoek for rest of your tables by data first approach